# tfruns failed to create a directory

Tags: r, keras

currently I am using keras in R for lstm networks. I would like to conduct hyperparameter tuning using the tfruns package. When I try to use the training_run() function an error occurs which is:

> NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory:
>   runs/2019-08-28T08-49-21Z/...

I already tried to resolve by updating R and all packages and executing R as an administrator, but this did not work. Has anyone an idea how to fix this? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Where is your working directory?

Comment: This is a bug and has been fixed [here](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/pull/868). Should be working if you install the dev version of keras.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer!